# Button-set implementation with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I use this metro style framework: http://metroui.org.ua/ and there is a button-set functionality: http://metroui.org.ua/buttons-set.php

Here is the basic implementation:

```
<div class="button-set" data-role="button-set">
      <button>button 1</button>
      <button class="active">button 2</button>
      <button>button 3</button>
</div>
```

**I wonder if it is possible to use it with knockout?** Let's say I would like to bind it to an observable property of my viewModel, how can I proceed to have my value updated automatically when selected button change?

I know we have other solutions like: http://jsfiddle.net/cuhuak/Rswbk/ but it could be nice if I succeed with this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ko custom bindings...

```
ko.bindingHandlers.buttonSet = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        value($(element).find('button.active').data('value'));
        $(element).find('button').on('click', function () {
            $(element).find('button.active').removeClass('active');
            value($(this).data("value"));
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).find('button.active').removeClass('active');
        $(element).find('button[data-value=' + value().toString() + ']').addClass('active');
    }
};
```

And for the HTML:

```
<div class="button-set" data-role="button-set" data-bind="buttonSet: val">
      <button data-value="1">button 1</button>
      <button data-value="2" class="active">button 2</button>
      <button data-value="3">button 3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution work pretty well except I removed the line `value($(element).find('button.active').data('value'));` in the init part. One question: in the init part, you have some code to removeClass then addClass. We found the same in the update part. When debugging, I clearly see that it works but I didn't understand why doing it at 2 different places? Thanks anyway.

Comment: The line you removed was used to initialize the view model attribute with the initial position of the 'active' class. The first removeClass/addClass (in the click event handler) is used to change the 'active' class when clicking on the button. The second removeClass/addClass is used to change the 'active' class when changing the view model attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative way that doesn't require a lot of jQuery parsing. In fact, no jQuery at all--just pure knockout.

From the [Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)

> Note 1: Passing a “current item” as a parameter to your handler
>   function
>
> When calling your handler, Knockout will supply the current model
>   value as the first parameter. This is particularly useful if you’re
>   rendering some UI for each item in a collection, and you need to know
>   which item’s UI was clicked.

**HTML**

We'll load the items from a `ko.observableArray()` So we can easily manipulate it via JS. To show this in the view, we use a `foreach`.

Via Knockout HTML comments, we can set two conditions, show the `li` that has the `active` class, or not.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: places">
    <li>
        <!-- ko if: $root.activeItem() !== $data -->
          <span data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.setActive"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: $root.activeItem() !== $data -->
          <span data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.setActive, attr: { class: 'active'}"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now we simply pass in the `place` to the function `setActive()`. This assigns itself to the `ko.observable()` `activeItem`. In the markup above each item is asked if it is the `activeItem` in the loop.

**JavaScript**

```
function MyViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.places = ko.observableArray(['London', 'Paris', 'Tokyo']);
  self.setActive = function(place) { self.activeItem(place) }
  self.activeItem = ko.observable()
}
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

**Example**

http://codepen.io/ajkochanowicz/pen/maylx